# Can't get CoffeeScript to recognize a function in a js file

Tags: coffeescript, philips-hue, framerjs

I am writing a simple app in Coffeescript to control a Philips Hue light. I have included [this module](https://github.com/blargoner/jshue) into my project. The below code seems to work fine up until I try to set the color of the lights using `setLightState`. The compiler says the function isn't a function. I don't quite understand why it doesn't recognize the function.

```
# Connect with Philips Hue bridge
jsHue = require 'jshue'
hue = jsHue()

# Get the IP address of any bridges on the network
hueBridgeIPAddress = hue.discover().then((bridges) => 
    if bridges.length is 0
        console.log 'No bridges found. :('
    else 
        (b.internalipaddress for b in bridges)
).catch((e) => console.log 'Error finding bridges', e)

if hueBridgeIPAddress.length isnt 0 # if there is at least 1 bridge
    bridge = hue.bridge(hueBridgeIPAddress[0])  #get the first bridge in the list

    # Create a user on that bridge (may need to press the reset button on the bridge before starting the tech buck)
    user = bridge.createUser('myApp#testdevice').then((data) =>
        username = data[0].success.username
        console.log 'New username:', username
        bridge.user(username)
    )

    if user?
        #assuming a user was sucessfully created set the lighting to white
        user.setLightState(1, {on:true, sat:0, bri:100, hue:65280}).then((data) =>
            # process response data, do other things
        )
```

Comment: Please provide the full error message.

Comment: exactly what I say in my question. It says setLightState is not a function.

Comment: Well, good luck solving your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see on the [github page of the jshue lib](https://github.com/blargoner/jshue), `bridge.createUser` does *not* directly return a `user` object.

Instead the example code sets the `user` variable *inside* the `then` function of the returned [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then):

```
bridge.createUser('myApp#testdevice').then(data => {
    // extract bridge-generated username from returned data
    var username = data[0].success.username;

    // instantiate user object with username
    var user = bridge.user(username);
    user.setLightState( .... )
});
```

It can be expected that - using this approach - the `user` variable will be set correctly and `user.setLightState` will be defined.

#### A self-contained example:

Take [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/MoMolog/pen/WzOyRE) for example:

```
url = "https://api.ipify.org?format=json"

outside = axios.get(url).then (response) =>
  inside = response.data.ip
  console.log "inside: #{inside}"
  inside

console.log "outside: #{outside}"
```

The console output is

```
outside: [object Promise]
inside: 178.19.212.102
```

You can see that:

1. the `outside` log is **first** and is a **`Promise` object**
2. the `inside` log comes **last** and contains the actual object from the Ajax call (in this case your IP)
3. the `then` function implicitly returning `inside` does not change anything

Comment: The thing is that with Coffeescript the last line of the function `bridge.user(username)` is returned and set to `user` so my code is effectively doing what you are suggesting.... or at least it should be.

Comment: @cHorse Not true. `bridge.createUser` returns **immediately** (a `Promise` object). On success of some internal mechanism (probably an Ajax call) the Promise invokes the function passed to it's `then` method **later** with the data from the Ajax call as argument. That the function passed to the Promise's `then` method implicitly returns it's last expression (because of CoffeeScript) doesn't help, the return value of this function is discarded anyway. In fact the whole problem is not related to CoffeeScript at all.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying. `createUser` takes some amount of time to come back. While thats going on my code attempts to call `setLightState` on an object that hasn't been initialized yet. Hence the "not a function" error.

Comment: Updated to add a stripped-down example.